# Python - Change a comma to a decimal in a list

Tags: python, formatting, python-3.7

I'm usting Python 3.7. I'm trying to convert a European decimal point, i.e. a comma into a decimal point (i.e. a dot).

The original file is a .csv file.

The code I have is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # split data values into list
    data = line.split("\t")

    data = "{,:.}".format(data)
    print(data)
```

The `data = "{,:.}".format(data)`  is causing issue.

The output I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conPrep.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = "{,:.}".format(data)
KeyError: ','
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Sample of data]

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
from io import StringIO
import locale
import sys
from locale import atof

data = sys.stdin.readlines()

reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
loc = locale.getlocale()
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'german')
for row in reader:
    print([atof(x) for x in row])
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conPrep.py", line 14, in <module>
    print([atof(x) for x in row])
  File "conPrep.py", line 14, in <listcomp>
    print([atof(x) for x in row])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\locale.py", line 326, in atof
    return func(delocalize(string))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Data.Temperatura Media (C).Temperatura Minima (C).Temperatura Maxima (C).Precipitacao (mm).Final de Semana.Consumo de cerveja (litros)'
```

Comment: post a testable input sample

Comment: The Source CSV and the conPrep.py files can be downloaded here: [link](https://gofile.io/?c=sL4x6C)

Comment: better post it here

Comment: Use replace instead: `line.replace(',','.')`

Comment: @SapanZaveri I tried, but got similar error.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I added the sample image of the CSV.

Comment: @SapanZaveri The issue with that is that all commas, including spacers in the CSV are coverted to a dot when they should be a tab (\t). Example output with ```line.replace..``` : ```2015-01-01."27.3"."23.9"."32.5".0.0.25.461```

Comment: @TattooedJoey yeah I got it because it will be operated on each line. You have to process on data variable

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `replace` function defined on the string class

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # split data values into list
    data = line.split("\t")
    data = data.replace(',', '.')
    print(data)
```

Comment: Doesn't work: Get the error:

```Traceback (most recent call last):File "conPrep.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = data.replace(',', '.')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `locale` and `csv` built in modules of `python`

See example below

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO
import locale
from locale import atof

data = StringIO("""item1,item2,item3,item4
02/12/2015\t12,3\t1,3\t1.000,3\t1
02/12/2015\t32,3\t1,3\t1.000,3
02/12/2015\t2,3\t0,3\t1.000,3
02/12/2015\t1,3\t1.220,3\t3.000,3
""")

#Uncomment the below line to work with the csv file
#with open('test.csv') as data:
reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
loc = locale.getlocale()
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'german')
next(reader)
for row in reader:
    print([atof(x) if i>0 else x for i,x in enumerate(row)])
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)
```

will print

```
[12.3, 1.3, 1000.3, 1.0]
[32.3, 1.3, 1000.3]
[2.3, 0.3, 1000.3]
[1.3, 1220.3, 3000.3]
```

**Edit**

replace the `data = StringIO...` with the line `with open('filename.csv') as data:`

Comment: I've added my code and output to the bottom of my question, under the picture. I think I did something wrong.

Comment: looks like you have header in the csv file.

Comment: New error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conPrep.py", line 17, in <module>
    print([atof(x) for x in row])
  File "conPrep.py", line 17, in <listcomp>
    print([atof(x) for x in row])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\locale.py", line 326, in atof
    return func(delocalize(string))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '01/01/2015."27.3"."23.9"."32.5".0.0.25461'```

Comment: obviously the firs item is a date it cannot be converted to float.

Comment: Updated to skip the date in the first column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203527/discussion-between-abhilb-and-tattooedjoey).